# ScrollView to fit its content in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I m new to objective-C and I need to set dynamic height to ScrollView according to its content. I have a UIView and in it I have UIScrollView. I have some UILabels, UIButtons etc on a view. Now it is showing extra space and I can scroll to the bottom even I don't have data.So if the data is completed I need to stop scrolling. How can I do it?

```
[testscroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
[testscroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,800)];//static size to UISCrollView


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [button setFrame:rect];
    [button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeLeft]; 
    NSString *settitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item.Name]; 
    [button setTitle:settitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *tagValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section+1,i]; 
    button.tag=[tagValue intValue];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [hlcell.contentView addSubview:button];
    [button release];

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you plz post some more code?

Comment: I have some UILabels,UIButtons in it one after the other.Can u please tell me what elz code should I post..Bcoz there are many labels and buttons I have created in the view .

Comment: you set the UILabel and UIButton dynamically???

Comment: UIButtons size are set statically but the no of buttons wil depend on array count which may vary.But I need to set UILabels dynamically..Dont know  that part also..First UILabels will appear nd then UIButtons in a custom UITableview acting like gridview

Comment: -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];[button setFrame:rect];[button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeLeft]; NSString *settitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item.Name]; [button setTitle:settitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];NSString *tagValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section+1,i]; button.tag=[tagValue intValue];[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];[hlcell.contentView addSubview:button];

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your scrollView `contentSize` according to your data.
Like i have an `array` and i want to manage scrolling size then i did this.

```
[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 100*[ary count]/4)];
```

in this array i have images with height of 100 so `100*[ary count]`

Comment: But I have some UILabels ,UIButtons in it one after the other.I dont have array itself.As per ur code if I set then if the content increases it is not showing any scroll..What should I do ?

Comment: hey isha you just get check your labels and buttons height.. like your have 10 button of  50 height then 10*50 or just adjust according your requirement...

Comment: Actually I created buttons in a custom TableView acting like gridview with four buttons in each row.The no of rows depend upon the array count.I created them like this;

Comment: ok if you have 4 button in one row then just divide 100*[ary count] by 4,

Comment: -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];[button setFrame:rect];[button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeLeft];
NSString *settitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item.Name];
[button setTitle:settitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];NSString *tagValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section+1,i];
button.tag=[tagValue intValue];[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];[hlcell.contentView addSubview:button];

Comment: no i do have some uilabels also.  displaydate =[[UILabel alloc]init];
    [displaydate setFrame:CGRectMake(150, 330,300, 50)];
    displaydate.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor blackColor];  
    displaydate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",result];
    [self.view addSubview:displaydate]; after this the uibuttons will start

Comment: hey if you have table view then what the need to use scroll view?

Comment: mean you are adding label in scrollview then a table..m i right

Comment: I need to provide Scoll only to ScrollView but not to tableView bcoz as I move scroll downwards in tableView then content will move upwards and sometimes the upwards data would hide and user cannot get notify it.and moreover I need to set some UILabels dynamically in it .So gone for ScollView

Comment: set one int value.you can use the for loop for set dynamic UILabel.and use the int++ the last int value of UILabel  use in scrool view.

Comment: ok so just use label_count * label_height and table_height yo set scrollable content